# Using VBA to authenticate to CoinBase Pro, invalid signature

Tags: excel, vba, signature, coinbase-api

I am trying to call the Coinbase Pro API, but keep getting invalid signature. I have followed the directions on CoinBase Pro, read tons of related articles here, and nothing really points to an issue. I have tried hashing the timestamp + method + fullURL, I have tried just the API endpoint as the documentation states. I have verified the hashing and base64 functions are getting the proper results. I have tried decoding the secret as stated by the documentation on CoinBase, but this yields non-readable characters. So I tried to base64 decode the secret using online tools, but that yields a non-decodable error message. One article mentioned changing the parameters to lowercase, so I tried all kinds of combinations, still not working.

Something to note is that the secret is already 64 bytes. The documentation says that the decoded secret should be 64 bytes. So I tried both the decoded and non-decoded secret.The documentation says to base64 encode the results of the SHA256 hash, but the function I am using already does this. So I tried both encoded and non-encoded just for posterity, and still yield the invalid signature error message.

There is a getEpochTime function that calls the /time endpoint. Here is the site where I got the HMAC_SHA256 code, although I had to change the reference to MSXML2.DOMDocument reference to MSXML2.DOMDocument60.
https://www.excelhowto.com/macros/excel-vba-base64-hmac-sha256-and-sha1-encryption/

Here are the websites that I used to verify the hashing and encryption:
https://devpal.co/base64-decode/
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online#/google_vignette

I am currently storing the api key, secret, and passphrase in an Excel sheet for now for easy testing. When creating the api key, I copied the data from the screen and pasted it into the Excel sheet to avoid human error. I also verified the api key has View/Trade/Transfer privileges.

Any constructive help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set oXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim URL As String
    Dim appKey As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim Passphrase As String
    Dim TimeStamp As String
    Dim Secret As String
    Dim HashText As String
    Dim Hash As String
    Dim API As String
    Dim sBody As String
    
    API = "/v2/accounts"
    TimeStamp = GetEpochTime
    URL = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(3, 2) & API
    appKey = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(6, 2).Value
    Secret = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(7, 2)                        'Base64DecodeString( )
    Passphrase = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(8, 2)

    HashText = TimeStamp & "GET" & URL
    Signature = Base64_HMACSHA256(HashText, Secret)
        
    oXmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False                     ', "", ""
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-KEY", appKey
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", TimeStamp
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", Passphrase
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-SIGN", Signature
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    oXmlHttp.send
    
    While oXmlHttp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    sBody = oXmlHttp.responseText

    MsgBox sBody
End Sub

Function GetEpochTime() As Double
    
    Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set oXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim URL As String
    URL = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(3, 2) & "/time"
    oXmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    oXmlHttp.send
    GetEpochTime = GetJSON_Key(oXmlHttp.responseText, "epoch")
    
End Function

Function Base64_HMACSHA256(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String)

    Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
 
    TextToHash = asc.Getbytes_4(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey
 
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    Base64_HMACSHA256 = Base64EncodeFromBytes(bytes)
    
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing
    
End Function
 
Function Base64EncodeString(ByVal sText As String) As String
    
    Dim byt() As Byte
    
    byt = VBA.StrConv(sText, VbStrConv.vbFromUnicode, 1033)
    
    Base64EncodeString = Base64EncodeFromBytes(byt)
    
End Function

Function Base64EncodeFromBytes(ByRef byt() As Byte) As String

    Dim oXML  As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set oNode = oXML.createElement("base64")
    oNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    
    oNode.nodeTypedValue = byt
    Base64EncodeFromBytes = oNode.Text
    
    Debug.Assert TypeName(Base64EncodeFromBytes) = "String"
    Set oNode = Nothing
    Set oXML = Nothing
    
End Function

Function Base64DecodeString(ByVal sText As String) As String

    Dim byt() As Byte
    byt = Base64DecodeToBytes(sText)
    
    Base64DecodeString = VBA.StrConv(byt(), VbStrConv.vbUnicode)

End Function

Function Base64DecodeToBytes(ByVal sEncoded As String) As Byte()
    
    Debug.Assert TypeName(sEncoded) = "String"
    
    Dim oXML  As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set oNode = oXML.createElement("base64")
    
    oNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    oNode.Text = sEncoded
    
    Base64DecodeToBytes = oNode.nodeTypedValue
    
    Set oNode = Nothing
    Set oXML = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was, it would take an entire page just to describe how I got it to work. Instead, here is the code. Copy/paste this into a new module in your Excel workbook and run the TestAPIConnection subroutine. Coinbase Pro credentials are in a sheet named "Configuration", and are referenced in the function called CBPro_Private_API. There is also a public API function that you can use for non-authenticated requests. Hope you find this useful.

Remember to add References to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" and "Micrrosoft Scripting Runtime".

[Configuration Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqhbY.png)

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestAPIConnection()
    
    Dim sMethod As String
    Dim API As String
    Dim sBody As String
    Dim sResult As String
    
    API = "/accounts"
    sMethod = "GET"
    sBody = ""
    sResult = CBPro_Private_API(sMethod, API, sBody)        
    'You will need to parse the resulting JSON string       
    MsgBox sResult

End Sub

Function CBPro_Public_API(sMethod As String, API As String, sBody As String) As String
    
    Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set oXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim URL As String
    URL = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(3, 2) & API
    
    oXmlHttp.Open sMethod, URL, False                     ', "", ""
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    oXmlHttp.send sBody
    
    'This is used when the ASync parameter on the .Open call is set to true
    While oXmlHttp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    CBPro_Public_API = oXmlHttp.responseText
    
End Function

Function CBPro_Private_API(sMethod As String, API As String, sBody As String) As String
    
    Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set oXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    Dim URL As String
    Dim appKey As String
    Dim sSignature As String
    Dim sPassPhrase As String
    Dim sTimeStamp As String
    Dim sSecret As String
    Dim sHashText As String
    Dim Hash As String
    
    'Get Setup data from the Configuration sheet
    appKey = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(4, 2).Value
    sSecret = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(5, 2)
    sPassPhrase = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(6, 2)
    URL = Sheets("Configuration").Cells(3, 2) & API
    
    'Create the hashed signature for verification by the server
    sTimeStamp = GetEpochTime
    sHashText = sTimeStamp & sMethod & API & sBody
    sSignature = GenerateSignature(sHashText, sSecret)
    
    'Call the API endpoint
    oXmlHttp.Open sMethod, URL, False
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-KEY", appKey
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-SIGN", sSignature
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", sTimeStamp
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", sPassPhrase
    oXmlHttp.send sBody
    
    'Wait for a response
    While oXmlHttp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    CBPro_Private_API = oXmlHttp.responseText
    
End Function

Function GenerateSignature(ByVal sTextToHash As String, sSharedSecretKey As String) As String
    
    Dim asc As Object
    Dim enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
    
    enc.Key = Base64DecodeToBytes(sSharedSecretKey)
    TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    GenerateSignature = Base64EncodeFromBytes(bytes)
    
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing
    
End Function

Function Base64_HMACSHA256(ByVal sTextToHash As String, sSharedSecretKey As String) As String

    Dim asc As Object
    Dim enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
    
    SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey
    TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash)
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    Base64_HMACSHA256 = Base64EncodeFromBytes(bytes)
    
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing
    
End Function

Function Base64EncodeFromBytes(ByRef byt() As Byte) As String

    Dim oXML  As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set oNode = oXML.createElement("base64")
    oNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    
    oNode.nodeTypedValue = byt
    Base64EncodeFromBytes = oNode.Text
    
    Debug.Assert TypeName(Base64EncodeFromBytes) = "String"
    Set oNode = Nothing
    Set oXML = Nothing
    
End Function


Function Base64DecodeToBytes(ByVal sEncoded As String) As Byte()
    
    Dim oXML  As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set oNode = oXML.createElement("base64")
    
    oNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    oNode.Text = sEncoded
    
    Base64DecodeToBytes = oNode.nodeTypedValue
    
    Set oNode = Nothing
    Set oXML = Nothing
    
End Function

Function GetEpochTime() As Double
    
    'Get Epoch Time from server
    Dim sResponse As String
    sResponse = CBPro_Public_API("GET", "/time", "")
    GetEpochTime = CDbl(GetJSON_Key(sResponse, "epoch"))
    
End Function
```